# How do I absolutely position something in React Native relative to a parent's parent?

Tags: css, react-native, css-position, absolute

I want to absolutely position a Font Awesome icon I have in a React Native project relative to the parent of a parent, not the icon's direct parent.

However, when I was looking into it, I found the following on the following page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position

> `position` in React Native is similar to regular CSS, but everything is set to `relative` by default, so `absolute` positioning is always relative to the parent.

As such, if I have something like the following, how can I position the icon relative to the grandparent `TouchableOpacity`, and not the parent `View`? Thank you.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {}}
>
    <View>
        {/* Other markup here. */}
    </View>
    <View>
        {/* Want to position this icon relative to TouchableOpacity, not View. */}
        <FontAwesome name="heart" />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: could you use `onLayout` on a `View` wrapping your items within `TouchableOpacity`, get it's measurements and set your positioning values to state then use those values to position (via style) your `FontAwesome` icon

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing. I know that the left View is a certain width, so I can adjust my `left` and `top` values accordingly to get the intended effect, but it feels sloppy and I would prefer a cleaner way, thus the question.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your markup, then you would want to have the `View` absolutely positioned like the following:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {}}
>
    <View>
        {/* Other markup here. */}
    </View>
    <View
        style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            ...
        }}
    >
        <FontAwesome name="heart" />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now, the entire view is absolutely positioned in relation to the `TouchableOpacity`. Therefore the same applies to its children, aka. your icon.

Comment: I see. Thanks. That's tricky though, because the two Views are currently in a `flex: row` layout and the View with the icon has `flex: 1`. I see what you're saying though. Not ideal, but I get it. Guess I'm going to have to fudge this (like everything else in React Native), unless there's a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's tricky, because I always use this. Presumably you have more content inside the Views giving the fact that you said that you Views have `flex: row`. If you want the icon to be absolutely positioned, then the icon belongs to its own `View`. Or you could move the icon outside and have `<FontAwesome style={{ position: 'absolute' }} ...>`. Idea is that the items you want to have absolutely positioned should be together with other elements that are not absolutely positioned. Kind of get my point? :)

Comment: Yes, I could put the icon completely outside the Views. That's an idea. Thanks.